# Circle to Circle Collision Response not working as Expected

Tags: javascript, typescript, canvas, physics

I'm working on an HTML Canvas demo to learn more about circle to circle collision detection and response. I believe that the detection code is correct but the response math is not quite there.

The demo has been implemented using TypeScript, which is a typed superset of JavaScript that is transpiled to plain JavaScript.

I believe that the problem exists within the checkCollision method of the Circle class, specifically the math for calculating the new velocity.

The blue circle position is controlled by the mouse (using an event listener). If the red circle collides from the right side of the blue circle, the collision response seems to work correctly, but if it approaches from the left it does not respond correctly.

I am looking for some guidance on how I can revise the checkCollision math to correctly handle the collision from any angle.

Here is a CodePen for a live demo and dev environment:
[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NvOPNW)

```
class DemoCanvas {
    canvasWidth: number = 500;
    canvasHeight: number = 500;
    canvas: HTMLCanvasElement = document.createElement('canvas');
    constructor() {
        this.canvas.width = this.canvasWidth;
        this.canvas.height = this.canvasHeight;
        this.canvas.style.border = '1px solid black';
        this.canvas.style.position = 'absolute';
        this.canvas.style.left = '50%';
        this.canvas.style.top = '50%';
        this.canvas.style.transform = 'translate(-50%, -50%)';
        document.body.appendChild(this.canvas);
    }

    clear() {
        this.canvas.getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }

    getContext(): CanvasRenderingContext2D {
        return this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    }

    getWidth(): number {
        return this.canvasWidth;
    }

    getHeight(): number {
        return this.canvasHeight;
    }

    getTop(): number {
        return this.canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    }

    getRight(): number {
        return this.canvas.getBoundingClientRect().right;
    }

    getBottom(): number {
        return this.canvas.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
    }    

    getLeft(): number {
        return this.canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    }
}

class Circle {
    x: number;
    y: number;
    xVelocity: number;
    yVelocity: number;
    radius: number;
    color: string;
    canvas: DemoCanvas;
    context: CanvasRenderingContext2D;

    constructor(x: number, y: number, xVelocity: number, yVelocity: number, color: string, gameCanvas: DemoCanvas) {
        this.radius = 20;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.xVelocity = xVelocity;
        this.yVelocity = yVelocity;
        this.color = color;
        this.canvas = gameCanvas;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext();
    }

    public draw(): void {
        this.context.fillStyle = this.color;
        this.context.beginPath();
        this.context.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        this.context.fill();
    }

    public move(): void {
        this.x += this.xVelocity;
        this.y += this.yVelocity;
    }

    checkWallCollision(gameCanvas: DemoCanvas): void {
        let top = 0;
        let right = 500;
        let bottom = 500;
        let left = 0;

        if(this.y < top + this.radius) {
            this.y = top + this.radius;
            this.yVelocity *= -1;
        }

        if(this.x > right - this.radius) {
            this.x = right - this.radius;
            this.xVelocity *= -1;
        }

        if(this.y > bottom - this.radius) {
            this.y = bottom - this.radius;
            this.yVelocity *= -1;
        }

        if(this.x < left + this.radius) {
            this.x = left + this.radius;
            this.xVelocity *= -1;
        }
    }

    checkCollision(x1: number, y1: number, r1: number, x2: number, y2: number, r2: number) {
        let distance: number = Math.abs((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2));
        // Detect collision
        if(distance < (r1 + r2) * (r1 + r2)) {
            // Respond to collision
            let newVelocityX1 = (circle1.xVelocity + circle2.xVelocity) / 2;
            let newVelocityY1 = (circle1.yVelocity + circle1.yVelocity) / 2;

            circle1.x = circle1.x + newVelocityX1;
            circle1.y = circle1.y + newVelocityY1;

            circle1.xVelocity = newVelocityX1;
            circle1.yVelocity = newVelocityY1;
        }
    }
}

let demoCanvas = new DemoCanvas();
let circle1: Circle = new Circle(250, 250, 5, 5, "#F77", demoCanvas);
let circle2: Circle = new Circle(250, 540, 5, 5, "#7FF", demoCanvas);
addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    let mouseX = e.clientX - demoCanvas.getLeft();
    let mouseY = e.clientY - demoCanvas.getTop();
    circle2.x = mouseX;
    circle2.y = mouseY;
});

function loop() {
    demoCanvas.clear();
    circle1.draw();
    circle2.draw();
    circle1.move();
    circle1.checkWallCollision(demoCanvas);
    circle2.checkWallCollision(demoCanvas);
    circle1.checkCollision(circle1.x, circle1.y, circle1.radius, circle2.x, circle2.y, circle2.radius);
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
requestAnimationFrame(loop);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Elasic 2D collision

The problem is likely because the balls do not move away from each other and then in the next frame they are still overlapping and it gets worse. My guess from just looking at the code.

#### A simple solution.

Before you can have the two balls change direction you must ensure that they are positioned correctly. They must be just touching, (no overlay) or they can get caught up in each other.

#### Detect collision, and fix position.

```
   // note I am using javascript.
   // b1,b2 are the two balls or circles
   // b1.dx,b1.dy are velocity (deltas) to save space same for b2


   // get dist between them
   // first vect from one to the next
   const dx = b2.x - b1.x;
   const dy = b2.y - b1.y;

   // then distance
   const dist = Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);

   // then check overlap
   if(b1.radius + b2.radius >= dist){ // the balls overlap
        // normalise the vector between them
         const nx = dx / dist;
         const ny = dy / dist;

         // now move each ball away from each other 
         // along the same line as the line between them
         // Use the ratio of the radius to work out where they touch
         const touchDistFromB1 = (dist * (b1.radius / (b1.radius + b2.radius)))         
         const contactX = b1.x + nx * touchDistFromB1;
         const contactY = b1.y + ny * touchDistFromB1;

         // now move each ball so that they just touch
         // move b1 back
         b1.x = contactX - nx * b1.radius;
         b1.y = contactY - ny * b1.radius;

         // and b2 in the other direction
         b2.x = contactX + nx * b2.radius;
         b2.y = contactY + ny * b2.radius;
```

#### If one is static

If one of the balls is static then you can keep its position and move the other ball.

```
// from contact test for b1 is immovable
if(b1.radius + b2.radius >= dist){ // the balls overlap
    // normalise the vector between them
     const nx = dx / dist;
     const ny = dy / dist;

     // move b2 away from b1 along the contact line the distance of the radius summed
     b2.x = b1.x + nx * (b1.radius + b2.radius);
     b2.y = b1.y + ny * (b1.radius + b2.radius);
```

Now you have the balls correctly separated a you can calculate the new trajectories

### Changing the trajectories.

There are a wide variety of ways to do this, but the one I like best is the elastic collision. I created a function from the [Elastic collision in Two dimensional space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision#Two-dimensional) wiki source and have been using it in games for some time.

The function and information is in the snippet at the bottom.

Next I will show how to call the function continuing on from the code above

```
 // get the direction and velocity of each ball
 const v1 = Math.sqrt(b1.dx * b1.dx + b1.dy * b1.dy);
 const v2 = Math.sqrt(b2.dx * b2.dx + b2.dy * b2.dy);

 // get the direction of travel of each ball
 const dir1 = Math.atan2(b1.dy, b1.dx);
 const dir2 = Math.atan2(b2.dy, b2.dx);

 // get the direction from ball1 center to ball2 cenet
 const directOfContact = Math.atan2(ny, nx);

 // You will also need a mass. You could use the area of a circle, or the
 // volume of a sphere to get the mass of each ball with its radius
 // this will make them react more realistically
 // An approximation is good as it is the ratio not the mass that is important
 // Thus ball are spheres. Volume is the cubed radius
 const mass1 = Math.pow(b1.radius,3);
 const mass1 = Math.pow(b2.radius,3);
```

And finally you can call the function

```
 ellastic2DCollistionD(b1, b2, v1, v2, d1, d2, directOfContact, mass1, mass2);
```

And it will correctly set the deltas of both balls.

Moving the ball position along their deltas is done after the collision function

```
 b1.x += b1.dx;
 b1.y += b1.dy;
 b2.x += b1.dx;
 b2.y += b1.dy;
```

If one of the balls is static you just ignore the deltas.

### Elasic 2D collision function

Derived from information at [Elastic collision in Two dimensional space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision#Two-dimensional) wiki

```
// obj1, obj2 are the object that will have their deltas change
// velocity1, velocity2 is the velocity of each
// dir1, dir2 is the direction of travel
// contactDir is the direction from the center of the first object to the center of the second.
// mass1, mass2 is the mass of the first and second objects.
//
// function ellastic2DCollistionD(obj1, obj2, velocity1, velocity2, dir1, dir2, contactDir, mass1, mass2){
// The function applies the formula below twice, once fro each object, allowing for a little optimisation.


// The formula of each object's new velocity is 
//
// For 2D moving objects
// v1,v2 is velocity  
// m1, m2 is the mass 
// d1 , d2 us the direction of moment
// p is the angle of contact; 
//
//      v1* cos(d1-p) * (m1 - m2) + 2 * m2 * v2 * cos(d2- p)
// vx = ----------------------------------------------------- * cos(p) + v1 * sin(d1-p) * cos(p + PI/2)
//                    m1 + m2

//      v1* cos(d1-p) * (m1 - m2) + 2 * m2 * v2 * cos(d2- p)
// vy = ----------------------------------------------------- * sin(p) + v1 * sin(d1-p) * sin(p + PI/2)
//                     m1 + m2

// More info can be found at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision#Two-dimensional

// to keep the code readable I use abbreviated names
function ellastic2DCollistionD(obj1, obj2, v1, v2, d1, d2, cDir, m1, m2){

    const mm = m1 - m2;
    const mmt = m1 + m2;
    const v1s = v1 * Math.sin(d1 - cDir);

    const cp = Math.cos(cDir);
    const sp = Math.sin(cDir);
    var cdp1 = v1 * Math.cos(d1 - cDir);
    var cdp2 = v2 * Math.cos(d2 - cDir);
    const cpp = Math.cos(cDir + Math.PI / 2)
    const spp = Math.sin(cDir + Math.PI / 2)

    var t = (cdp1 * mm + 2 * m2 * cdp2) / mmt;
    obj1.dx = t * cp + v1s * cpp;
    obj1.dy = t * sp + v1s * spp;
    cDir += Math.PI;
    const v2s = v2 * Math.sin(d2 - cDir);    
    cdp1 = v1 * Math.cos(d1 - cDir);
    cdp2 = v2 * Math.cos(d2 - cDir);    
    t = (cdp2 * -mm + 2 * m1 * cdp1) / mmt;
    obj2.dx = t * -cp + v2s * -cpp;
    obj2.dy = t * -sp + v2s * -spp;
}
```

**Note** just realized that you are using a typeScript and the function above is specifically type agnostic. Does not care about `obj1`, `obj2` type, and will add the deltas to any object that you pass.

You will have to change the function for typeScript.

Comment: Is there a way to adapt this solution for circle in circle collision. I have one circle and another one which is inside the first circle. I want the second one to bounce around inside the first one.

Answer (score 2):

The velocity vector should change by a multiple of the normal vector at the collision point, which is also the normalized vector between the circle mid points.

There are several posts here and elsewhere on elastic circle collisions and the computation of the impulse exchange (for instance [Collision of circular objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28122594/collision-of-circular-objects/28252655#28252655), with jsfiddle for planet billiard https://stackoverflow.com/a/23671054/3088138).

If `circle2` is bound to the mouse, then the event listener should also update the velocity using the difference to the previous point and the difference of time stamps, or better some kind of moving average thereof. The mass of this circle in the collision formulas is to be considered infinite.

As you are using `requestAnimationFrame`, the spacing of the times it is called is to be considered random. It would be better to use actual time stamps and some effort at implementing the Euler method (or whatever the resulting order 1 integration method amounts to) using the actual time increments. The collision procedure should not contain a position update, as that is the domain of the integration step, which in turn makes it necessary to add a test that the disks are actually moving together.